# Scala: Call function only with specified path-dependent type param

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

Lets have a class A with inner class.

```
class A {
    class InnerA
}
```

And class Test that holds instance of A

```
class Test(inst: A) {
    def someFun(p: inst.InnerA) {} //Neither A#InnerA, Nor inst.type#InnerA
}
```

Now i need to **restrict someFun to be called only with parameter of type InnerA of specified inst** (member of Test). (Not by any instance of InnerA that is achieved with A#InnerA)

```
val a: A = new A
val inna: a.InnerA = new a.InnerA
val test: Test = new Test(a)
```

But when i write this code:

```
test.someFun(inna)
```

type checker warns that "Type mismatch, expected: inst.type#InnerA, actual: a.InnerA"

**Please suggest how can it be done.**

---

Similar but *NOT suitable* solution is of form

```
def fun(a: A)(p: a.InnerA) {}
```

---

As for application: An A class is Enumeration class, and InnerA is Enumeration.Value class. And Test is a class i'd like to restrict to use with only specified Enumeration. And "inna" are instances of enumeration values that are constructed inside the Enumeration subclass.

Answer (score 1):

With `new Test(a)` you lose the information that `a` becomes `test.inst`. For example, the following works:

```
class Test(val inst: A) {
  def someFun(p: inst.InnerA) = ()
}

val test: Test = new Test(new A)
val inna = new test.inst.InnerA
test.someFun(inna)
```

Comment: Is there any way to save this type information? As for application: A class is Enumeration class, and InnerA is Enumeration.Value class. And Test is a class i'd like to restrict to use with only specified Enumeration. And "inna" are instances of enumeration values that are constructed inside the Enumeration subclass. So it's not convenient to construct them outside.

Comment: Why would `A` be a `class` and not a singleton `object` if it inherits the `Enumeration` trait?

Comment: "A" here is in place of Enumeration, to show the similarity between A.InnerA and Enumeration.Value . And we can create singleton B that extends A. But it's not important it context of this discussion. I tried to be as simple as possible